# Reactjs axios post response is not returning anything

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm using axios.post() to edit a mysql database on the back end of my Reactjs app. The data gets through the post request to the back end fine. But I need to know when the post request finished and return some data from it to know if what the back end code ran worked correctly. I've tried the following where newEdit is an object with the information that's need in the back end

```
axios
 .post('http://ip:3001/edit_table', newEdit)
 .then((response) => { 
     console.log("response: ",response);
 }, (error) =>{
     console.log("error: ",error)
 });
```

Neither of the console log statements get ran. Once again, the object does get to the routed nodejs file fine, I am just unable to get any kind of response. Anyone know what's happening? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your backend code is OK and return response then you can following below example that works perfectly.

```
const updateData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.put(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`, {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        id: id,
                        title: post.title,
                        body: post.body,
                        userId: 1
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
                    }
                })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(json => console.log(json));
                console.warn(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.warn(error);
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your backend is returning a response to the client. 
You can either use `res.send` or `res.json`. res.send([body]) is used to send HTTP response to the client while res.json(body) is used to send JSON response.

**res.send([body])**

```
res.send(new Buffer('whoop'));
res.send({ some: 'json' });
res.send('<p>some html</p>');
```

**Example:**

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('hello world')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

**res.json([body])**

```
res.json(null)
res.json({ user: 'tobi' })
res.status(500).json({ error: 'message' })
```

**Example:**

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.json({ success: true })
})

app.listen(3000)
```

**References:**

[Express](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html) API reference

Node.js response object methods [res.send and res.json](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_response_object.htm)

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction I cant seem to find any documentation on this function. Do you know where I could get more information about it? Thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer with examples and references. I hope it helps :) Goodluck!